# KDE file type settings vs evolution

Tags: kubuntu, email, evolution, default-programs, attachment

I am using Evolution on Kubuntu 20.04. Before opening a file (like .pdf or .jpg) it is easy to permanently adjust the tool which is used to open the file type (like nomacs, okular, etc.).

However the system settings seem to have no influence on the behavior of Evolution. When opening e-mail attachments, the selection of default viewers is horribly wrong (like using GIMP to open .pdf).

I tried to fix the issue and search for corresponding settings but I failed.

Is there a way to make Evolution respect the system settings? If not, is there a way to separately adjust the default tools used by Evolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround for the issue. If you receive an attachment that is opened with the wrong tool by default, right-click the attachment and choose "Open with other application...", then choose the right tool manually. Evolution will remember the selection.

Still I wonder why there is not explicit setting anywhere.